# How to calculate sen on javascript using math tag?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, area, calc

I'm coding a site that calculates the area of ​​regular polygons, and I'm having problems building the formula.

Here is the formula:

```
((a**2)*b)/(4*tan(π/b)))

a = Size of the side
b = Number of the sides
```

For exemple:

a = 10

b = 5

Area = 172

i tryed these syntaxs, but the result is not 172:

```
((10**2) * 5) / (4 * Math.tan(math.PI / 5))
((10**2) * 5) / (4 * Math.tan(3.1415 / 5))
```

I now that the problem is here: `"(4 * Math.tan(3.1415 / 5))"`, because if i put the directly the value of the "tan(π/5)", which is "0.726542528", the formula works...

`((10**2) * 5) / (4 * 0.726542528) = 172`

Which is the correct syntax?

Comment: You really need to use proper [markdown](/markdown) here, because it's very hard to understand what you actually tried.

Comment: The second expression seems to work as it is, the first-one has a typo, should be `Math.tan` instead of `math.tan`. With that fixed, the expression works.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `((a**2)b)/(4tan(π/b)))` implemented in JS, then the first step is to actually write that out fully instead of omitting implied operations:

```
((a**2) * b) / (4 * tan(π/b))
```

And of course, a bunch of parentheses are irrelevant here:

```
a**2 * b / (4 * tan(π/b))
```

Then you map that to JS, which it pretty much already is except for that `tan` and `π`, both of which we can get from the `Math` object:

```
const { PI:π, tan } = Math;

function getPolygonArea(a,b) {
  return a**2 * b / (4 * tan(π/b));
}
```

Done. That formula works now and yields 172.04774005889672 for `getPolygonArea(10,5)`.